# Closed questions claim to be deleted

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, profile-page

In the profile on the "votes" tab, closed questions have a "(deleted)" label, even if they haven't been deleted:

[image: close votes]

Only the question with the colored background at the bottom really is deleted. Questions one and three are not and have not been deleted, they only got closed.

It seems like the "(deleted)" note shows up as soon as the question is *closed*, and so should read "(closed)" instead. This would be more useful than a "(deleted)" note since deletion is already indicated by the background color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's your vote that was deleted.  The post itself may or may not be deleted.

For more reference, [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175611/175248) detailing when this occurs will be of benefit.